# Opening up Rails API to users within a closed network

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-4, server, backend, rails-api

I am attempting to run a React/Rails Website locally for 2-3 users within a closed network.  Currently, the users can reach the React portion (I have that set to port 80).  The problem is, the API calls I have set to my Rails backend are all on `localhost:3001` and the users have zero access to that database when I try to submit HTTP requests.

I know it's a CORS issue but I thought the code below would allow any domain to make the necessary request.

```
 Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
   allow do
     origins '*'

     resource '*',
       headers: :any,
       methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
   end
end
```

Server side work is not my forte, so I may be missing something glaring.  Any idea how to open up that backend so the networked users can make API Calls on their end?

React is on this ip: `http://192.168.2.70:80/`
API calls on this port: `3001`

Example API call from front end (works on host computer; not on other users):

```
getData = () => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/pickup_deliveries')
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({
                    apiData: response.data})
                })
            .catch((error)=>{console.log(error);});
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

Unless I missed something, it looks like you're making a simple mistake that you're going to smack yourself for.

Typically, a CORS issue in a JavaScript application would yield a CORS/pre-flight request error error in your browser's JavaScript console.

**The Misconception**

The JavaScript that makes up a React application is downloaded by the client (i.e. your users). After that, **the fetch call is executed on the client's computer**. The fetch request doesn't originate from the *server*, but rather from the *remote end*.

It works on your computer because both React and the Rail API are hosted on your computer, so `localhost:3001` resolves correctly. However, on your *users* computer, the React app attempts to find a service running on port 3001 on *their* computer.

**Initial Solution**

You need to tell React to reach out to the IP server that's hosting the API, like this:

```
getData = () => {
    axios.get('http://192.168.2.70:3001/api/v1/pickup_deliveries')
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                apiData: response.data})
            })
        .catch((error)=>{console.log(error);});
}
```

**Long Term Solution (for deployment)**

In the future, look into `dotenv`, which will allow you to set React environment variables. You could have a `.env.local` file, and a `.env.production` file.

In the local file, you could put:

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_SERVER=http://localhost:3001
```

and in the `production` on you could put:

```
REACT_APP_URL=http:/<server_ip>:3001
```

Then, in your program, do something like:

```
getData = () => {
    axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL + "/api/v1/pickup_deliveries")
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                apiData: response.data})
            })
        .catch((error)=>{console.log(error);});
}
```

This will automatically resolve to `localhost` when serving React using `npm run start` and then resolve to `<server_ip>` when you are serving the static files generated by `npm run build`.

Feel free to comment on this answer. I would be happy to answer any other questions you have. Welcome to React!

Comment: Yo!  Thanks for the indepth answer!  It looks great but unfortunately, I won't be able to test for a few days but I'll let you know.

Comment: @AttemptedMastery No problem, it's a common point of confusion when coming from the server-rendered world (i.e. Rails templates, etc.). I experienced it myself. Let me know if it works, and if not we will figure it out.

Comment: Oddly enough, localhost works but when I use the networked iP (````192.168.2.70````), I am getting an ````ERR_CONECTION_TIMED_OUT````.  This applies to both the "server" and the users.

Comment: @AttemptedMastery Have you checked your firewall?

Comment: yup... actually, I turned it off completely to test it.  Still, the client and the server are getting connection refused.  I figured, at the very least, I would be able to complete a request locally on the server VIA that network IP.  Maybe something bigger is going on :/

Comment: Did you change your proxy setting? What does your Axios request URL look like?

Comment: ````getData = () => {
  axios.get('http://192.168.2.70:3001/api/v1/pickup_deliveries')
       .then((response) => {
          this.setState({
           apiData: response.data})
        })
      .catch((error)=>{console.log(error);});
 }````

Comment: I am sure I am missing some pertinent info, so I apologize if that is the case.  Could the localhost IP in rails be different than the "network ip" in React?  I know it shouldn't be, but is that possible?

Comment: Can you post your `package.json` in your question? I would like to see the proxy settings. Your customers are able to get to http://192.168.2.70 and see React right?

Comment: Hey!  So, I got it by opening up request from any IP, as long as the port is 3001 with this command:

````rails server -p 3001 -b 0.0.0.0```` 

It is persisting and displaying the correct data!

EDIT:  Now, I need to figure out if there is a way for the data to show up on the client side without refreshing.  That's a whole different beat I'm assuming :D

Comment: Oh ok so rails only bound to loopback IP initially, gotcha. What do you mean "without refreshing"?

Comment: Yup!  So basically, to summarize, I need to learn how to utilize websockets (I think).  A user won't be able to see newly submitted data from another user until they refresh the page.  When they refresh the page, the server will then serve the newly submitted data.  I want that action done in real-time.  

Especially since this particular app will be mounted on a TV for people to see.. it needs to update in real-time as forms are submitted.

Comment: Yes, you're not able to do that through HTTP 1.1. HTTP 2 would be able to handle that, but support is limited and setup is not trivial. WebSockets and RPC are the best solution.

Comment: For the time being, I'm using ````setTimeout()```` to poll the server... it's not the best solution but given the amount of data persistence in my app, I think it'll suffice.

Comment: That's a perfectly valid solution for making simpler/older apps seem more responsive.

Comment: That's what I read!  I was relieved to hear that as well, because web sockets is something I would love to fiddle around with in a "lower stakes" situation :D.  I am excited to test it out though.  

Thanks for all your help brother!  I appreciate you sticking with me on this thread.